# OpenCV calcOpticalFlowFarneback: How to extract velocity vector values from specific pixels

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

The standard code for calcOpticalFlowFarneback python.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
ret, prev = cam.read()
prevgray = cv2.cvtColor(prev, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

coords = np.array([
    [230, 218, 205, 189, 176, 156],
    [145, 156, 162, 166, 166, 165]
])

total_magnitude = []

while True:

    ret, img = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev=prevgray,
                                        next=gray,
                                        flow=None,
                                        pyr_scale=0.5,
                                        levels=10,
                                        winsize=15,
                                        iterations=3,
                                        poly_n=5,
                                        poly_sigma=1.2,
                                        flags=0)

    mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[..., 0], flow[..., 1])
```

How can I get the average value of specific pixels from `mag` which represents the velocity vector/magnitude of specific pixels instead of the whole shape?

Here is what I tried:

```
    mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[..., 0], flow[..., 1])

    single_frame_magnitude = []

    for counter in range(coords.shape[1]):
        x = coords[:, counter][0]
        y = coords[:, counter][1]

        single_frame_magnitude.append(mag[x][y])

    total_frames_magnitude.append(np.mean(frame_mag_list))
```

Answer (score 2):

`coords` is simply 2D NumPy array where the first column contains the row locations and second column contains the column locations.  You can use these to index into the array in a vectorized form to obtain the values of interest, then find the average of those escaping the need for a loop all together:

```py
mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[..., 0], flow[..., 1])
values = mag[coords[:,0], coords[:,1]]
total_frames_magnitude.append(np.mean(values))
```

NB: In your first code snippet, the list you are changing is called `total_magnitude` yet in your example code snippet that follows after, it's called `total_frames_magnitude`.  I have assumed you meant the latter so I have used that as the list to change instead.